# FOSS Linux software to create fillable PDF form from existing documents

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, pdf, forms

The Pro version of Acrobat can [create fillable forms](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WSB3F26303-0F1D-494a-BC55-7BF7F6684B4D.html) from existing documents.

I am looking for a similar solution, but that is FOSS and runs on Linux.

I want to take existing PDF files that look like they should be forms and auto detect the form spots and add them in. As long as it gets close, I would be happy to add and delete a few missed extra forms by hand.

Answer (score 8):

LibreOffice has been mentioned already...

But **[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/)** is a lesser known software (a "Page Layouts Creating Program") which is able to output high-quality PDF files, not matched in feature-richness by any other Open Source application: It can create PDF/X, PDF/A, layers, fillable forms and much more.

Details about PDF forms creation here:

- **[Your first PDF form with Scribus](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Your_first_PDF_form_with_Scribus)**

Answer (score 7):

You can use LibreOffice for this, it should be installed by default on most Linux systems.

On the toolbar, go to “View -> Toolbar -> Form Control” and click it. This will add the Form Control toolbar to your Libre Writer interface.

After you have finished with the document, go to “File -> Export as PDF”. Make sure the “Create PDF Form” checkbox is selected. The most commonly used format for data submission is FDF, but you can select PDF, HTML or XML format as well.

Comment: Is there a programmatic API for this functionality?

Comment: Is possible to add a save button?